# Can I pull different data values with same attribute name, with just one click button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

I want to be able to pull different data values from same attribute name with just one click button. Is this possible with Jquery? So if I click buttom it will show me "01", if I click again it will show me "02" and so on. Here is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".more-info").click(function(){
   var getData = document.getElementsByClassName("showTitle");
   document.getElementById("gridModalLabel").innerHTML =
   $(".showtitle").data('prodname');
});


   });

</script>

 <div class="analytic-product showtitle" data-prodname="01" id="w3s"></div>
 <div class="analytic-product showtitle" data-prodname="02" id="w3s"></div>
 <div class="analytic-product showtitle" data-prodname="03" id="w3s"></div>

 <h4 class="modal-title" data-target="#gridSystemModal" id="gridModalLabel"></h4>
 <button class='btn btn-default btn-lg more-info' data-target='#gridSystemModal' data-toggle='modal' type='button'>Schedule Meeting</button>
```

Comment: why are you mixing jquery and vanilla javascript?

Comment: what is supposed to happen when you are already at last one? Please take the time to thoroughly read [ask]

Comment: This is possible but you would need to keep track of what was clicked globally and then check it to see which value to return.

Comment: @Isaac, it's not *vanilla javascript*. For what it's worth, jQuery *is* vanilla JavaScript. It's a hodge-podge of organically-growned layers upon code nobody wants to take responsibility for. The original incarnation was probably stolen from the Internet four years ago.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi `document.getElementById("gridModalLabel")` is vanilla, `$(document).ready` is not.

Comment: @Isaac, actually my point was that I believe direct DOM access (`getElementsByClassName()`, `getElementById()`) was part of the original code but the jQuery layer was added later. The questioner obviously cannot tell the difference between the two.

Comment: I'm a retired vet who is new to coding and pretty much learning on my own.  I'm still looking for better resources to understand and write code better. Thank you to the ones that actually did tried to help.

Answer (score -1):

I have created the solution using jquery. On each click the data attribute from div is appended to a target div I have created. I have updated the code to deal with undefined.

```js
$(function() {

  var $dataDivs = $('div.analytic-product');
  var $target = $('#target');
  var indexTracker = 0;


  $('.btn.more-info').on('click', function(e) {    
    if (indexTracker < $dataDivs.length)
      $target.append($($dataDivs[indexTracker++]).data('prodname') + "<br>");
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="analytic-product showtitle" data-prodname="01" id="w3s"></div>
<div class="analytic-product showtitle" data-prodname="02" id="w3s"></div>
<div class="analytic-product showtitle" data-prodname="03" id="w3s"></div>
<div id="target"></div>
<h4 class="modal-title" data-target="#gridSystemModal" id="gridModalLabel"></h4>
<button class='btn btn-default btn-lg more-info' data-target='#gridSystemModal' data-toggle='modal' type='button'>Schedule Meeting</button>
```

Comment: use `eq()` instead of making new jQuery object...note that if keep clicking will display "undefined"

Comment: Reason for downvote please? Doesn't the answer solve the intended question? Anyways, I would like to understand why the answer was downvoted.

Comment: @Danny Is this what you wanted? If yes, then you can accept the answer. If not, let me know I might be able to modify that. The problem with some users on StackOverflow is that they to show off their intelligence rather than helping the newcomers. Remember, everyone here is not an expert! So please do not make comments that can dissuade the beginners from posting questions again. Thanks.